# Substrate-Connect Integration For Custom Chain Without BootNodes In The Chain Spec JSON

Tags: bootnode, substrate-connect

**My question is: what is the best way to specify bootnodes for substrate-connect, inside the JS application, in this situation?**

We are integrating substrate-connect into a JS application that uses the Polkadot-JS API. I understand from these docs: https://docs.substrate.io/learn/light-clients-in-substrate-connect/ that the code for integrating substrate-connect into such an application looks like this:

```
import { ScProvider } from "@polkadot/rpc-provider/substrate-connect";
import { ApiPromise } from "@polkadot/api";
import jsonCustomSpec from "./MyChainSpec.json";
// Create the provider for the custom chain
const customSpec = JSON.stringify(jsonCustomSpec);
const provider = new ScProvider(customSpec);
// Establish the connection (and catch possible errors)
await provider.connect();
// Create the PolkadotJS api instance
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider });
await api.rpc.chain.subscribeNewHeads(lastHeader => {
  console.log(lastHeader.hash);
});
await api.disconnect();
```

However, our chain spec does not specify bootnodes. When validator nodes join, they use one of a set of available bootnodes in their node startup code, rather than relying on bootnodes in the spec. So bootnodes exist, they are just not in the spec.

Comment: Researching, I found one person who said that you can change the customSpec.JSON file's "bootNodes": field without a problem. (that is, you will connect to the correct chain. If that's true, then is this solution as simple as taking the raw spec json file and adding in an appropriate bootnode?

Comment: I also found the following... Your bootnode needs to listen on secure Websocket to catch with substrate connect:
* Node needs to listen on WS instead of default http --listen-addr /ip4/0.0.0.0/tcp/30333/ws (do no use --port in this case)
* Set a proxy with WS upgrade and SSL enabled, pointing a DNS
* Specify the WSS address of the bootnode in chainspecs (example: "/dns/astar-02.wss-bootnode.astar.network/tcp/443/wss/p2p/12D3KooWMfHf9G1Mtawz4qySe1EqaBmrieidqn2xnEYckUYkpe52")

Comment: So we might also want to start a node under those specifications for substrate connect to find, and then add that node as a bootnode in the raw spec json file. Can someone check my thinking on that? And do you really need a secure web socket or will any bootnode work?

Comment: Last question.... Where in all of the front end code would you place the code I included above? We are using a clone of the polkadot-JS apps front end, customized with pages for our own apps.